# Failed to map the path '/' MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL using web.config and I used MySQL Website Configuration for it. Problem is it makes my site show an error when running instead of running it. :D

This is my web.config SQL connection:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalMySqlServer" connectionString="password=PASS****;user id=9b443f_users;server=MYSQL5008.myWindowsHosting.com;database=db_9b443f_users" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="Sessions" description="Sessions" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="Profiles" description="Profiles" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="MemRecords" description="MySQL default application" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="True" requiresUniqueEmail="True" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="Roles" description="Roles" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

And this is the stack trace it shows me:

> [InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.]
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostConfigUtils.MapPathActual(String
>   siteName, VirtualPath path) +224
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(String
>   siteID, VirtualPath path) +865
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.GetPathConfigFilenameWorker(String
>   siteID, VirtualPath path, String& directory, String& baseName) +13
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String
>   siteID, String path, String& directory, String& baseName) +37
>   System.Web.Configuration.HostingPreferredMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String
>   siteID, String path, String& directory, String& baseName) +75
>   System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String
>   configPath) +9844796
>   System.Configuration.Internal.DelegatingConfigHost.GetStreamName(String
>   configPath) +11
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile() +134
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a
>   configuration file: Failed to map the path '/'.]
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
>   ignoreLocal) +658656
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
>   schemaErrors) +34    System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor(String
>   locationSubPath, Type typeConfigHost, Object[]
>   hostInitConfigurationParams) +328
>   System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigConfigurationFactory.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigConfigurationFactory.Create(Type
>   typeConfigHost, Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) +29
>   System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.OpenConfiguration(WebLevel
>   webLevel, ConfigurationFileMap fileMap, VirtualPath path, String site,
>   String locationSubPath, String server, String userName, String
>   password, IntPtr tokenHandle) +387
>   System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(String
>   path) +76
>   MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore.Initialize(String name,
>   NameValueCollection config) +437
>   System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings
>   providerSettings, Type providerType) +597
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.SecureInstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings
>   settings) +43
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitCustomStore(SessionStateSection
>   config) +87
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.InitModuleFromConfig(HttpApplication
>   app, SessionStateSection config) +9777245
>   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.Init(HttpApplication app)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +80    System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +64
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context,
>   HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +792
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext
>   context) +336
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext
>   context) +107
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +525

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that if I comment out these lines, the error won't appear and the site would work correctly:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="true" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="Sessions" description="Sessions" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

How do I fix it so I won't have to comment it out?

EDIT:

Used "[MySQL Website Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-website-config.html)" and fixed the error.